# AnyLogic: How to refer to an agent in a delay block in anylogic

Tags: anylogic, agent

I am building a DES-ABM hybrid model in AnyLogic.
The agents go through the DES blocks, among which multiple Delay blocks.

How do I

1. access an agent which is in a Delay block
   or peferrably
2. acces the specific agent which triggered the 'on enter' action of the delay block?

My ultimate goal is to open or close a valve object on the agent frame
So can I/ how do I
A. open or close the valve on the agent frame directly form the main/root frame (on which the Delay block is located)
or if that is not possible
B. send a message or trigger a statechart within the specific agent which will then open or close the valve from the agent's own frame?

I have tried to use the 'DelayBlockName'.agents() function, but this does not work and returns [] when I check it using traceln.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> access an agent which is in a Delay block or peferrably

use the keyword `agent`. These keywords differ for different library blocks so best start learning about the lightbulb and how it can help, see [here](https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2016/2/4/the-magic-lightbulb-and-how-it-can-help-your-anylogic-modelling).

> acces the specific agent which triggered the 'on enter' action of the delay block?

When you write `agent.` in the "On enter" block, every agent coming through will execute that code, so by definition, it is always the specific agent :)

> My ultimate goal is to open or close a valve object on the agent frame So can I/ how do I A. open or close the valve on the agent frame directly form the main/root frame (on which the Delay block is located) or if that is not possible B. send a message or trigger a statechart within the specific agent which will then open or close the valve from the agent's own frame?

this is something completely different to your original question and just... messy. Please limit questions to 1 topic so it is easy for us to answer :) (see [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more)

Comment: I have used agent.xxx and it indead finds the proper agent with all elements on the agent frame.I used

agent.valve_trafficsignIN.open();

to open the valve on the agent frame. It does not give me any errors when I run it. Also, when I print the information using traceln, it gives me the correct specs of the valve in question and it states that it is open. 
However, when I open the agent frame, the valve is still closed. Also, the changes that should happen in the model when the valve opens do not happen.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: @Yume glad you made progress. But think about it: How could I possibly help here? :) Open a new question (and mark this is helpful/solved) and add details so one can actually help. Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn more :)