# Setting up different delay for different entities entering through same delay

Tags: attributes, anylogic

[image][image][image]I want to set up different delay times for different entities entering in delay1.
[image]

one entry is directly from the source and another from delay2.

I understand that in "Arena" we do add attributes to the entities but here in AnyLogic, I don't know how to perform it. can anybody help me out?

Comment: Hi Manish, this is a very basic question with several answers here on SOF already, for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64681135/anylogic-how-to-refer-to-an-agent-in-a-delay-block-in-anylogic . Always first search if someone else asked the same thing before you, we have a huge knowledge base here already :) . Also, please always show what you tried already when asking here on SOF, see https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow . Helps us help you faster ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest option is to create a new custom agent that will be created by your source and pass through your flow diagram, with some variable that you can set to true when it is passing through the details a second time

[image]

[image]

And you just set this variable to true when it is going for rework.

[image]

And in the delay you can now access this variable and use it to set a different delay

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable time. But it is not working for me...ihave added new pictures of what i have done...pls have a look

Comment: In your screenshot the `rePass` variable lives on main... not inside your `Case` agent. See my example.